# Making an image disappear with :nth-of-typen only works with (0) and (1)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-transitions

I just completed the capstone project on Codecademy but wanted to have the man reading the journal disappear when going into smaller screen sizes. There are a total of 3 img-holder divs... I tried it but it also removes the image at the bottom as well...

```css
 .supporting .img-holder:nth-of-type(0) {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container supporting">
  <div class="img-holder">
  <img src="images/information-main.jpg">
    <div class="caption">
      <h2>It doesn't hurt to keep practicing</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsusssm dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Id accusantium, optio est prribus!</p>
      <p id="signature">Emmanuel, Sr Strategist at Hiring.com</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work when using 
[Live version is visible here](https://thomasbromehead.github.io/Colmar/)

Comment: It's 1-indexed, 0 isn't going to match anything.

Answer (score 1):

`:nth-of-type` selects elements based on their element type (e.g. `div`) within their scope. Meaning with a structure like:

```
div.supporting
  div.img-holder A
div.supporting
  div.img-holder B
div.supporting
  div.img-holder C
```

The selector `.supporting .img-holder:nth-of-type(1)` selects all three. `A` is the first of its type (`div`) within its parent. `B` is also the first of its type within its parent. Same for `C`.

Maybe you wanted `.supporting:first-child .img-holder` – this would select only `A`. (Note that this still assumes that particular `.supporting` is the first child of its container. This may not be so, and there are work-arounds. The simplest way to solve it is to have a specific class for the first `.supporting`, if it is meant to behave differently. This will work without complicated / hard-to-understand / hard-to-modify selectors, with great browser support.)

Answer (score 0):

nth-of-type, match elements types not element class so you can match it by its div, and remember that nth in css is not 0 index base is 1 index base so match the first one with 1

```
.supporting div:nth-of-type(1) {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `nth-of-type` is `1` indexed not `0` . So you should start from `1`.

Second, `nth-of-type` does not select the classes or the id's. It selects the type of the element, for example `div,p,img,h1` etc. There is no `nth-of-class` selector.

You should try to select your div based on your HTML. So you could use for example ( after inspecting your html structure )

`.supporting-1 + .supporting > .img-holder { display:none }`

Comment: Basing selectors on detailed specifics of the HTML structure can lead to terrible CSS. Small changes in the structure (e.g. introducing another element between `.supporting-1` and `.supporting` in your example) will break the CSS. IMHO it is much better to have general, easy-to-understand classes and not use more "advanced" selectors whenever possible.

Comment: @Aurel Bílý: Unless, of course, you actually *intend* for your CSS to break when such an element is introduced. No reason to introduce a unique class just to avoid using a combinator when doing the latter is the logical thing to do.

Comment: @BoltClock Of course, it depends on the context / scope of the project. In OP's case, which one do you think is the better choice?